# Multiple Matching Expressions Using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have an input file that I want to extract values from.  The input file has this sort of format:

```
 > P-phase pairs total =         5135
 > S-phase pairs total =         4155
```

I want to write a Perl script that matches the expression in this text file and outputs the value after the equals sign.  The code below can handle the output of the first value, but want I want to do is output the second value (4155) as well.  What would be the best way to amend this code, to allow multiple matching expressions? Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open (my $file, "<", "input.txt") || die ("cannot open ph2dt file.\n");
open (my $out, ">", "output.txt") || die ("cannot open outfile.\n");

while(my $line =<$file>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ / > P-phase pairs total =.*?(\d+)/) {
    print $1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if ($line =~ / > P-phase pairs total =.*?(\d+)/) {
```

with

```
if ($line =~ / > [PS]-phase pairs total =.*?(\d+)/) {
```

or

```
if ($line =~ / > .-phase pairs total =.*?(\d+)/) {
```

We might as well anchor the match to avoid needless matching and backtracking, and `.*?` should be avoided as it can cause major headaches. So we get:

```
if ($line =~ /^ > .-phase pairs total =\s*(\d+)/) {
```